# Sort combobox values alphabetically

Tags: vba, sorting, excel

I have a combobox in a userform for excel.  What is the easiest way to sort it alphabetically?  The values for it are hardcoded in vba and new ones are just added to the bottom so they are not in any kind of order already.

The userform is currently being used so that our users can import data from our database into excel.  The combobox is there so they can specify which client data to import.

Comment: Is this a list of fields and / or tables? Have you considered using a schema for the database to populate the listbox, rather than the hardcoded list?

Comment: That's a good point, as the list would probably come to me presorted any way.  The only issue I can see is security, and performance issues.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

As you are adding them, compare them to the values already in the combobox.
If they are less than the item you come across, the replace the item.
If they are not less than, then move on until you find something the item is less than.
If it cannot find the item, then add it to the end.

```
For X = 0 To COMBOBOX.ListCount - 1
  COMBOBOX.ListIndex = X
  If NEWVALUE < COMBOBOX.Value Then
     COMBOBOX.AddItem (NEWVALUE), X
     GoTo SKIPHERE
     End If
Next X
        COMBOBOX.AddItem (NEWVALUE)
SKIPHERE:
```

Answer (score 3):

It could easily be as follows :

```
Sub fill_combobox()
Dim LastRow, a, b As Long, c As Variant
ComboBox1.Clear
LastRow = Sheets("S1").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 2 To LastRow
ComboBox1.AddItem Cells(x, 2).Value
Next
  For a = 0 To ComboBox1.ListCount - 1
  For b = a To ComboBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ComboBox1.List(b) < ComboBox1.List(a) Then
c = ComboBox1.List(a)
    ComboBox1.List(a) = ComboBox1.List(b)
    ComboBox1.List(b) = c
       End If
  Next
  Next
End Sub
```

I have used in this template : [Sort combobox alphabetically](https://netmerkez.wordpress.com/2016/07/07/sorting-userform-combobox-alphabetically/)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Creating the array to sort isn't so hard as you might think.  See [Sorting Mulicolumn Listbox](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/05/24/sorting-a-multicolumn-listbox/).  You can put the List property right into a Variant type, sort that as an array, and dump that Variant Array back into the List property.  Still not great, but it's the best VBA's got.

Answer (score 1):

VBA lacks a built-in sorting function for such things. Unfortunately.

One cheap way that does not involve implementing/using one of the popular sorting algorithms yourself is to use the .NET Framework's `ArrayList` class via COM:

```
Sub test()
  Dim l As Object
  Set l = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

  ''# these would be the items from your combobox, obviously
  ''# ... add them with a for loop
  l.Add "d"
  l.Add "c"
  l.Add "b"
  l.Add "a"

  l.Sort

  ''# now clear your combobox

  Dim k As Variant
  For Each k In l
    ''# add the sorted items back to your combobox instead
    Debug.Print k
  Next k

End Sub
```

Make this routine part of `UserForm_Initialize`. This will of course fail if the framework is not installed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  However, this is implemented as an excel add-in on other peoples computers, and although I do have the .Net framework there is no way to be sure that they have it.

Comment: Yeah. In this case you have to use one of the plethora of sorting solutions that are available for VBA. Here is a random one I found through Google, using Heapsort: http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/vbasic/1.htm

Comment: Though probably a minimalistic bubblesort won't kill your performance dead either, for a handful of combobox items. And it's less code.

Comment: Yeah.  It's kind of absurd that I have to first build an array to sort, then build a sort function, then add it to the combobox, lol.  I though there might be a built-in function or something.  It might be easier just to stick the values into an excel sheet in the add-in, sort them, and then plug the values in.  I don't know if I want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

This uses ADO library, which I guess will be available on most computers (with Excel installed).

```
Sub SortSomeData()
Dim rstData As New ADODB.Recordset
rstData.Fields.Append "Name", adVarChar, 40
rstData.Fields.Append "Age", adInteger

rstData.Open

rstData.AddNew
rstData.Fields("Name") = "Kalpesh"
rstData.Fields("Age") = 30
rstData.Update

rstData.AddNew
rstData.Fields("Name") = "Jon"
rstData.Fields("Age") = 29
rstData.Update

rstData.AddNew
rstData.Fields("Name") = "praxeo"
rstData.Fields("Age") = 1
rstData.Update

MsgBox rstData.RecordCount
Call printData(rstData)

Debug.Print vbCrLf & "Name DESC"
rstData.Sort = "Name DESC"
Call printData(rstData)

Debug.Print vbCrLf & "Name ASC"
rstData.Sort = "Name ASC"
Call printData(rstData)

Debug.Print vbCrLf & "Age ASC"
rstData.Sort = "Age ASC"
Call printData(rstData)

Debug.Print vbCrLf & "Age DESC"
rstData.Sort = "Age DESC"
Call printData(rstData)
End Sub

Sub printData(ByVal data As Recordset)
    Debug.Print data.GetString
End Sub
```

Hope this gives you enough background to get started.
FYI - This is a disconnected recordset (simpler version of .net dataset for in memory tables).