# Need help adding alphabetical sort to combobox

Tags: excel, vba

I have a combobox in an Excel UserForm that I would like to sort alphabetically. I don't have any idea how to add this function, and I would appreciate any help. Here is my VBA:

```
Private Sub Userform_Initialize()
    ' Sets range for ComboBox list
        Dim rng As Range, r As Range
        Set rng = Sheet1.Range("H2:H65536")

        For Each r In rng
            AddUnique r.value
        Next r
    End Sub


Sub AddUnique(value As Variant)
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim inList As Boolean

        inList = False
        With Me.ComboBox1
            For i = 0 To Me.ComboBox1.ListCount - 1
                If Me.ComboBox1.List(i) = value Then
                    inList = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i

            If Not inList Then
                .AddItem value
            End If
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: Where are the values for the combo box coming from?  If the source if a range on a worksheet (like perhaps `Sheet1.Range("H2:H65536")`), then simply sort the values on the worksheet **before** adding them to the combo box.  If you want to sort with VBA, record a macro while you sort the data, and use the VBA code that Excel generates for you. (If you're not sure how to sort on the worksheet manually, then you'll need to find a good Excel tutorial to get you started..)

Comment: Also, are you really adding 65,000 items to your combo box? I think you'll have an issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort combobox values alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860366/sort-combobox-values-alphabetically) ... (There are several other existing examples as well.)

Comment: I guess I should have clarified. I can’t sort the excel sheet that the combobox values are coming from, as it it a grouped list (project, sub project, foreman, etc) I don’t have 65,000 entries, but it’s a dynamic list, and my combobox code filters out duplicates from about 1000 or more entries. There will only be around 10 entries in the combobox, and it would be nice for this to be alphabetical. It took me a while to find code to make this work correctly. Being new to VBA, I’m not sure how to modify what I have, which is why I asked. Can anyone assist me with modifying the code I have so far?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use a `Dictionary` to create a collection of only the unique value in your range, then sort it prior to adding the items to your combobox.

> If you haven't done so already, add a reference library to your project by going to the Tools menu, then select References. Scroll down the list and find the **"Microsoft Scripting Runtime"** and check it.

Then it's a simple matter of looping through all the entries -- only adding an item if it doesn't exist already. I lifted a sorting routine from [ExcelMastery](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/#Sorting_by_keys). Then add the items to your combobox.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Userform_Initialize()
    ' Sets range for ComboBox list
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("H2:H65536")

    '--- create a dictionary of the items that will be in
    '    the combobox
    Dim uniqueEntries As Object
    Set uniqueEntries = New Scripting.Dictionary
    For Each r In rng
        '--- all dictionary keys must be a string
        Dim keyString As String
        If IsNumeric(r) Then
            keyString = CStr(r)
        Else
            keyString = r
        End If
        If Not uniqueEntries.exists(keyString) Then
            uniqueEntries.Add CStr(keyString), r
        End If
    Next r
    Set uniqueEntries = SortDictionaryByKey(uniqueEntries)
    CreateComboboxList uniqueEntries
End Sub

Private Sub CreateComboboxList(ByRef dictList As Scripting.Dictionary)
    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In dictList.keys
        Debug.Print "Adding " & key
        'Me.combobox1.AddItem key
    Next key
End Sub

'------------------------------------------------------------------
'--- you should put this in a module outside of your userform code
Public Function SortDictionaryByKey(dict As Object, _
                                    Optional sortorder As XlSortOrder = xlAscending) As Object
    '--- from ExcelMastery
    '    https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/#Sorting_by_keys
    Dim arrList As Object
    Set arrList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    ' Put keys in an ArrayList
    Dim key As Variant, coll As New Collection
    For Each key In dict
        arrList.Add key
    Next key

    ' Sort the keys
    arrList.Sort

    ' For descending order, reverse
    If sortorder = xlDescending Then
        arrList.Reverse
    End If

    ' Create new dictionary
    Dim dictNew As Object
    Set dictNew = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' Read through the sorted keys and add to new dictionary
    For Each key In arrList
        dictNew.Add key, dict(key)
    Next key

    ' Clean up
    Set arrList = Nothing
    Set dict = Nothing

    ' Return the new dictionary
    Set SortDictionaryByKey = dictNew

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and patience! I've been using Excel for a long time, but have only been using VBA for a few weeks now. I replaced my code with the code you provided. My combobox is now blank. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What's printing out from the `Debug.Print` statement? You may also add another `Debug.Print` in the `For Each r In rng` loop as well to see how/why the dictionary is (not) getting populated. This code worked for the test data I used.